# How can I get the duplicate multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, array-intersect

I have an multidimensional array:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

)
```

Look at the first index (or zero) and third index (number two index), the values in a,b,c,d is equal 1,2,3,4. Assuming that the array is equal, or no different of them; my question is, how can I catch the array which equal, my purpose to show users about the value input duplicate,

I have already been using `array_unique`. This is the result :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

)
```

But I just want to get duplicate data, not remove the data duplicate.

```
// first : get all data, if the data same / duplicate take only one data

$unique = array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR);

// then, get the data which duplicate with

$diffCellUniq = array_diff_key($data, $unique);

// so print the result 

print_r($diffCellUniq); exit;



   Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: *my purpose to show users about the value input duplicate* - paraphrase your goal. You want to get only unique items or to get indexes of duplicating items??

Comment: I'm sorry for paraphrase my goal, I want to get indexes of duplicating items @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// first : get all data, if the data same / duplicate take only one data

$unique = array_unique($data, SORT_REGULAR);

// then, get the data which duplicate with

$diffCellUniq = array_diff_key($data, $unique);

// so print the result

print_r($diffCellUniq); exit;
```

---

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you. >:)

Answer (score 0):

To get only duplicating items preserving their keys - use the following approach with `array_keys`, `array_fill_keys`, `array_merge`, `array_unique` and `array_intersect_key` functions:

```
$dup_keys = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {  // $arr is your initial array
    $keys = array_keys($arr, $item);
    if (count($keys) > 1) {
        $dup_keys = array_merge($dup_keys, $keys);
    }
}

$dup_keys = array_unique($dup_keys);
$dup_items = array_intersect_key($arr, array_fill_keys($dup_keys, 0));

print_r($dup_items);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 4
        )
)
```

[**DEMO link**](https://eval.in/631421)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique):

```
$var = array_unique($YOUR ARRAY, SORT_REGULAR);
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php
$your_array = array (
    0 => array
        (
            'a' => '1',
            'b' => '2',
            'c' => '3',
            'd' => '4',
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            'a' => '1',
            'b' => '5',
            'c' => '3',
            'd' => '4',
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            'a' => '1',
            'b' => '2',
            'c' => '3',
            'd' => '4',
        ),  
);

$tmpArray = array ();

foreach ($your_array as $row) 
    if (!in_array($row, $tmpArray)) array_push($tmpArray, $row);

var_dump($tmpArray);
?>
```

Check online example as well https://eval.in/631417

Comment: look at my question to get the result of the code @Syed

Answer (score -1):

Since array_unique doesn't work on multi-dimensional array, one way to achieve this is to serialize this array and apply array_unique function on this.

Once unique function is applied, we can unserialize it and get it back in array format.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#97285

Try this:

```
$input = array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input))
$input = array_map("unserialize", $input);
```

Comment: Yes we do use array_unique. Since it's not single dimensional, we need to do these adjustments by serializing and unserializing.