# If there are several records with the same value in array column - take one record with minimum value of other column

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have multidimensional array looks like that:

```
Array3: [
    0 => array:2 [
            model_id => 1
            price => 2000
         ]      
    1 => array:2 [
            model_id => 2
            price => 3000
         ]
    2 => array:2 [
            model_id => 1
            price => 1500
         ]
   ]
```

Now I need to check if value of model_id occurs more than once, if so I need to take this one where price value is lower. In this example I have model_id = 1 twice so I should take second one because have lowest price.

How can I do this? I have tried this methods:

[how can I get the duplicate multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222346/how-can-i-get-the-duplicate-multidimensional-array-in-php)

[PHP: Check for duplicate values in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948946/php-check-for-duplicate-values-in-a-multidimensional-array)

[Finding Duplicate Values in Multi-dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218587/finding-duplicate-values-in-multi-dimensional-array)

But I still can't deal with the problem. Resulting array should look like that:

```
Array2: [
    0 => array:2 [
            model_id => 2
            price => 3000
         ]
    1 => array:2 [
            model_id => 1
            price => 1500
         ]
   ]
```

Comment: @Cid I have edited my post

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: @AbraCadaver No, no, I tested the proposed solutions but I haven't implemented any specific of it yet. I'm ashamed to admit but I'm afraid solution I was looking for wont be the best solution in my case. I will try to deal with the problem with proposed array filtering but I think i will need diffrent way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You can sort descending by `price`, then extract and index on `model_id` so the last one (lowest `price` of each `model_id` index) will overwrite the others:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'price'), SORT_DESC, $array);
$result = array_column($array, null, 'model_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `foreach` should do it as:

```
foreach($arr as $e) {
    if (isset($res[$e["model_id"]]))
        $res[$e["model_id"]]["price"] = min($res[$e["model_id"]]["price"], $e["price"]);
    else $res[$e["model_id"]] = $e;
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/0CKL2)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of associative array keys to enforce uniqueness and compare prices:

```
<?php
// Our data
$array = [
    [ 'model_id' => 1, 'price' => 2000 ],
    [ 'model_id' => 2, 'price' => 3000 ],
    [ 'model_id' => 1, 'price' => 1500 ]
];

// Store the final result
$result = [];

// Loop the data
foreach( $array as $v )
{
    // If this model_id has not been encountered or if the price is lower than what's stored then make it the new price
    if( !isset( $output[ $v[ 'model_id' ] ] ) || $v[ 'price' ] < $output[ $v[ 'model_id' ] ][ 'price' ] )
    {
        $output[ $v[ 'model_id' ] ] = $v;
    }
}

// Get rid of the unique keys
$output = array_values( $output );

print_r( $output );
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [model_id] => 1
            [price] => 1500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [model_id] => 2
            [price] => 3000
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by them for `model_id` than use `min` function

```
$groupByModelId = [];
foreach($a as $v){
  $groupByModelId[$v['model_id']][] = $v['price'];
}
$searchModelId = 1;
echo min($groupByModelId[$searchModelId]);
```

[Working DEMO](https://3v4l.org/W6mJJ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more method,

```
function array_column1($input, $column_key = null, $index_key = null)
{
    $result = [];
    $i      = 0;
    foreach ($input as $v) {
        $k            = $index_key === null || !isset($v[$index_key]) ? $i++ : $v[$index_key];
        // fetching all the values for model id
        $result[$k][] = $column_key === null ? $v : (isset($v[$column_key]) ? $v[$column_key] : null);
    }
    // fetching minimum for every model_id
    $result = array_map("min", $result);
    return $result;
}
$temp = array_column1($arr, 'price', 'model_id');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/AnE56).

I used this function from official php [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#118915).

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort array function for get first min value records, then use temp array and run foreach function for remove duplicate records.

Below code is working fine for me.

```
<?php


$arr = array(
        [   
            'model_id' => 1,
            'price' => 2000
        ],
        [
            'model_id' => 2,
            'price' => 3000
        ],
        [
            'model_id' => 1,
            'price' => 1500
        ]
    );

    usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
        return $a['price'] - $b['price'];
    });

    $input = $arr;
    $temp  = array();
    $keys  = array();

    foreach ( $input as $key => $data ) {
        unset($data['price']);
        if ( !in_array($data, $temp) ) {
            $temp[]     = $data;
            $keys[$key] = true;
        }
    }

    $output = array_intersect_key($input, $keys);

    print_r($output);
```